# Question about the Radiative Transfer Equation (RTE) Phase function term

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, laplace-transform

I am new to this subject. I am trying to understand what is the purpose of the phase function

$$
    ∂u/∂t=-v∘∇u-v( μ_{a}+μ_{s})u+∫vμ_s p_{s} (Ω^{'}→Ω)u(r,Ω^{'},t)ⅆΩ^{'}+q(r,Ω,t)
$$

Were
u= angular Photon density,

v= velocity of photon,

$\Omega$=Solid angle

$μ_{a}$ and  $ μ_{s}$  are absorption and scattering coefficients

$p_{s} (Ω^{'}→ Ω)$  is the phase function

q= emission source

t= time

The first term is the dot product of the velocity with the photon density. The photon density may be replace with Specific Intensity. This sets forth a Diffusion equation. Second term is the lost due to scattering and absorption. The third term is the phase function to account for returning photons. The fourth term is  emission source.

The way I understood a Phase function $
p_{s} (Ω^{'}→ Ω)
$ a equation that returns a probabilistic profile of scattered photons returning to the solid angle volume from other solid angles $\Omega^{'}$ understand that this is a probabilistic function that accounts for photons that scattered away from the solid angle volume and then returned to the volume from scattering events else where.

How do you recommend that I describe phase function? What  experimental  at hand offers the best function to describe this event? Please , comment.

Comment: Your question would be improved if you could provide some context and properly typeset your equations.

Comment: This is my first experience entering the typesets.  will add more context.